# Solving coupled nonlinear differential equations

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a differential equation that is as follows:

```
%d/dt [x;y] = [m11 m12;m11 m12][x;y]
mat = @(t) sin(cos(w*t))
m11 = mat(t) + 5 ; 
m12 = 5;
m21 = -m12 ;
m22 = -m11 ;
```

So I have that my matrix is specifically dependent on t.  For some reason, I am having a super difficult time solving this with ode45.  My thoughts were to do as follows ( I want to solve for x,y at a time T that was defined):

```
t = linspace(0,T,100) ; % Arbitrary 100
x0 = (1 0); %Init cond
[tf,xf] = ode45(@ddt,t,x0)

function xprime = ddt(t,x)
ddt = [m11*x(1)+m12*x(2) ; m12*x(1)+m12*x(2) ]
end
```

The first error I get is that

```
Undefined function or variable 'M11'.
```

Is there a cleaner way I could be doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running this within a script, which means that your function `ddt` is a [local function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html) instead of a [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html). That means it doesn't have access to your matrix variables `m11`, etc. Another issue is that you will want to be evaluating your matrix variables at the specific value of `t` within `ddt`, which your current code doesn't do.

Here's an alternative way to set things up that should work for you:

```
% Define constants:
w = 1;
T = 10;
t = linspace(0, T, 100);
x0 = [1 0];

% Define anonymous functions:
fcn = @(t) sin(cos(w*t));
M = {@(t) fcn(t)+5, 5; -5 @(t) -fcn(t)-5};
ddt = @(t, x) [M{1, 1}(t)*x(1)+M{2, 1}*x(2); M{1, 2}*x(1)+M{2, 2}(t)*x(2)];

% Solve equations:
[tf, xf] = ode45(ddt, t, x0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One glaring error is that the return value of function `ddt` is `xprime`, not `ddt`. Then as mentioned in the previous answer, `mm1` at the time of definition should give an error as `t` is not defined. But even if there is a `t` value available at definition, it is not the same `t` the procedure `ddt` is called with.

```matlab
mat = @(t) sin(cos(w*t))
function xprime = ddt(t,x)
    a = mat(t) + 5 ; 
    b = 5;
    ddt = [ a, b; -b, -a]*x
end
```

should work also as inner procedure.